# PHP to PostgreSQL insert unnested arrays into multiple rows

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, insert

I have some data in PHP arrays/variables ready to insert into a PostgreSQL table via an INSERT statement.

For a simple example say I have the following information:

```
$name= 'someName';
$time = array(1,2,3);
$elevation = array(100,200,300);
```

(In my real application these are double precision and potentially 1,000+ values)

I also have my postgresql table with columns "name","time","elevation"

I want to insert these in a single INSERT statement, and have been given multiple different ways to do this.

1. Loop and insert one data point (row) at a time.
2. Use unnest() on the arrays and do a single insert (fastest)

My question is can I pass a single variable name, and the un-nested arrays and have name repeated every row (ever array element), or do I need to construct a repeated array for name the equivalent count() as the other arrays?

An example statement:

*cr_query is a custom PHP pg_query wrapper we use

```
cr_query($conn,"INSERT INTO sometable (name,time,elevation) VALUES ({$name},{unnest($time)},{unnest($elevation)}););
```

This would insert into sometable:

```
ID     name      time    elevation
1     someName     1        100
2     someName     2        200
3     someName     3        300
```

Am I correct here or do I need to do something else?

EDIT:

Lets say I also have another variable "surface". Surface can be a double value or can be NULL. So I want to insert into the table to look like so:

```
ID     name      time    elevation    surface
1     someName     1        100          50
2     someName     2        200         NULL
3     someName     3        300          100
```

In PHP, using the method perscribed by klin below an array for surface in the unnest statement would become unnest(array[50,,100]); This throws an error like so:

(Error from my real data)

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "," LINE 3: ...-6,5.75E-6,5.75E-6,5.75E-6,5.75E-6]),unnest(array[,,,,,,,,,]... ^
```

EDIT 2:

Now that all of the "encoding" is working a new problem has popped up. Say the example column "surface" above is type double precision.

Say I am inserting an array, but for this set all of the data is null.

The essential piece is:

```
unnest(array[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null])
```

However, this array is of type string. Add a single value to it and it becomes the type of that numeric value, but I need to be able to handle this.

My question is: How do I insert an unnested array of all null values into a double precision column? (I tried to cast ::double precision) but it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your cr_query() function is not doing any magic things, your code is going to raise postgres syntax error. You can use unnest but you must prepare proper query text.
Try your code:

```
$name= 'someName';
$time = array(1,2,3);
$elevation = array(100,200,300);
echo "INSERT INTO sometable (name,time,elevation) VALUES ".
    "({$name},{unnest($time)},{unnest($elevation)})"

echo: INSERT INTO sometable (name,time,elevation) VALUES (someName,{unnest(Array)},{unnest(Array)})
```

Obviously it is not what we want to send to postgres. How to repair this?

```
$name= 'someName';
$time = array(1,2,3);
$elevation = array(100,200,300);
$timestr = 'array['. implode(',', $time). ']';
$elevstr = 'array['. implode(',', $elevation). ']';
echo "INSERT INTO sometable (name,time,elevation) ".
    "VALUES ('$name',unnest($timestr),unnest($elevstr));"

echo: INSERT INTO sometable (name,time,elevation) VALUES ('someName',unnest(array[1,2,3]),unnest(array[100,200,300]));
```

I think this is correct query. Note that I enclosed text variable '$name' in single quotes.

---

If you have nulls in your arrays you have to replace all empty strings to 'null' in prepared text for query.
Probably the simplest way to do it is to use str_replace(). 
As the conversion is getting more complicated it is handy to write a function (say "pgstr()") for that purpose.

```
function pgstr($array) {
    $str = 
        str_replace('[,', '[null,', 
        str_replace(',]', ',null]', 
        'array['. implode(',', $array). ']'));
    while (strpos($str, ',,') > 0) $str = str_replace(',,', ',null,', $str);
    return $str;
    }

$name= 'someName';
$time = array(1,2,3,4);
$elevation = array(100,null,300,null);
$surface = array(null,null,3.24,null);
$timestr = pgstr($time);
$elevstr = pgstr($elevation);
$surfstr = pgstr($surface);
echo 
    "INSERT INTO sometable (name,time,elevation,surface) ".
    "VALUES ('$name',unnest($timestr),unnest($elevstr),unnest($surfstr));";
```

Comment: I always thought that the only way how to insert multiple rows in single INSERT statement is to use more '(value1, value2)' parts separated by comma. But I tried this and it works - thanks! Do you know where is this behaviour described in postgres documentation? I failed to find it.

Comment: This is trial-and-error knowledge. Some time ago I wanted to generate a combination of elements from two arrays, so I tried `select unnest(array[1,2,3]), unnest(array[1,2,3])`. The result is somehow logical but I do not know about any formal documentation of this. Try also `select unnest(array[1,2]), unnest(array[1,2,3])` and so on.

Comment: I found some kind of warning in Postgres documentation: _Currently, functions returning sets can also be called in the select list of a query. For each row that the query generates by itself, the function returning set is invoked, and an output row is generated for each element of the function's result set. Note, however, that this capability is deprecated and might be removed in future releases._ [35.4.8. Functions returning sets](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/xfunc-sql.html).

Comment: @klin I will give this a run on Monday, looks like exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @klin I have added some additional issues to the question. Would love some help, your fist solution seems like it will work (after getting the added error figured out)

Comment: @klin Great, exactly what I needed. Thanks for everything.

Comment: @klin Found a small issue in the null replacement. If you have an array of form array(100,null,null,200) the return is unnest(array[100,null,,200])    I think this can be fixed by repeating the first string replace statement as a 4th replace.

Comment: @kpurdon - of course! Sorry for that oversight. I have just changed the function in answer.

Comment: @klin I hate to continue requesting your assistance, but, if your willing I have added an additional question to my original (EDIT2).

Comment: @kpurdon - "null::numeric" should be ok.